# conditional width sizing with styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, width

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

```
<SubTitle length={this.state.name}>{this.state.name}</SubTitle>
```

Im going to get random string to `this.state.name`,
and depends on the string length, I like to set width size.

```
const SubTitle = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
  width: ${async props => {
    let len;
    if (props.length) {
      len = await props.length.length;
    }
    return `${len}rem`;
  }};
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `length` as a prop name? It can easily be confused with `length` property on inbuilt types like strings and arrays.

Comment: you can use ` width: max-content`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using -

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

${props => (props.length ? css`
  width: //change the logic to whatever you want
` : css`
  width: //whatever default width
`)}
```